# scope.$apply doesn't kick off while using it with jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a checkbox that change its status between true/false with angular but I want to style it so it doesn't look like a standard checkbox. So my thought was to hide the checkbox and have a link (which I can style) that will trigger the checked/unchecked status of the checkbox.

So by using jquery I could easily achieve this. The problem is that angular doesn't pick this change up and I read that using scope.$apply(function(){}) and placing the jquery in there would sort that out. This is not the case however. Please help me, what am I missing here, is there another way I should be doing this?

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <a toggle><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
    <input ng-model="item.status" type="checkbox">
<div>
```

Script

```
app.directive('toggle', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).bind('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    $(this).next().prop('checked', false);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best if you don't hide it and make something else change it. Normally you would trigger change

<del>$(this).next().prop('checked', false).trigger('change');</del>

but this may not work in angular.

Instead, make the checkbox invisible and use a label which will trigger its matching checkbox (using `id` and `for`) using standard browser behavior and no javascript.

```
<input ng-model="item.status" type="checkbox" id="some-checkbox" /> <!-- hide this -->
<label for="some-checkbox" toggle><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></label>
```

*I don't know if the toggle syntax is correct in the given code, I just know that label click triggers checkbox change*

Comment: The label is the best idea and the most obvious. Just smacked myself for not thinking of that. As for the .trigger('change'). It makes no difference, when I remove the scope.$apply the checkbox unchecks but once I add it, nothing happens.

Comment: Ok I will remove that bit from the answer.